# Mysql, get data from another row in the same column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm a beginner in mySQL and php. [my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us7We.png)

I would like to know, how to get someones email address based on his username. So for instance if I know the username is: iamtheboss, how could I get his email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query you should use.

```
$query="SELECT email FROM userstable WHERE username='iamtheboss'";
```

or:

```
$username='iamtheboss';
$query="SELECT email FROM userstable WHERE username='$username'";
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT email FROM userstable WHERE username='iamtheboss'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've specified you're using PHP, the code you can use is:

```
      <?php $db = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","dbname");
      foreach($db->query("select * from tableName where username = 'iamtheboss'") as $row):
         echo $row['email'];
      endforeach;
      $db->close();
```

Note, you should really look up [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if you're working with Databases using a PHP dev-enviroment.

The use of [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) can also create a secure and neat infastructure when working with Databases.